# Missing Badges Thread

Tags: support, badges

Seeing how I think that I am missing a badge, and I don't think it is a good idea to open a thread for every time someone thinks he is missing a badge,

I hereby post a thread so people could post answers whenever they think they are missing a badge. Answers can be given in comments, since they are usually short and pointing out something that was overlooked before.

- **Please read [Badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) First**.
- Once your problem is solved please edit the conclusion into the answer.

Comment: I tagged it as [bug] despite not being exactly "buggy", please retag if incorrect.

Comment: I retagged as (support); please retag if my correction is incorrect.

Comment: Please read the **[badge FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)** first to check the details of the rules for a particular badge.

Answer (score 5):

I seem to be missing a [cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinals) badge. My profile says I have 144 upvotes on 21 non-CW questions.

I think that entitles me to a badge of some sort. However, it does not appear in my profile.

**Answer:** There are only 47 questions, tag badges are awarded for tags with 100+ questions.

Comment: @Theo: It is possible, I guess we'll have to wait for one of the developers to give us more insight on this matter.

Comment: There are only 47 questions on this tag. Tags are only considered for badges if they appear on at least 100 questions. See the [right-hand sidebar on the badge page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) and the [tag badges FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395).

Comment: FWIW: it took me weeks after getting 100+ upvotes on [tag:special-functions] to get the corresponding specialist badge. Probably something similar is happening to you...

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, I was looking for an explanation why my badge for the [(gap) tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap) is not yet awarded, and this is the only place where I've found that there must be 100+ questions with that tag (and for now, there are only 79).

Answer (score 4):

I think I am missing a [sportsmanship](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/65/sportsmanship) badge.

- http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/815/how-sporting-am-i-sportsmanship-badge reports 157 competing answers upvoted.
- http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1704/how-close-am-i-to-sportsmanship-badge reports 163 competing answers upvoted

Is there some technicality I am missing?

I figured I just hadn't answered enough questions, but Asaf showed me the data.se thingy, and it looks like I should have had the badge for months.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing a voxpopuli badge.

Today I used all 40 of my votes and yet I have not being awarded.

It even came up with a green tick saying I have completed this badge, but for some reason it does not show up in my badges count section and it has not being added to my badge count. Any way that this can be fixed?

Comment: It takes some time to register, as far as I remember (maybe because of the grace period where you can withdraw votes).

Comment: Ahh yes thank you. I have been awarded.