# Good Answer Badge not awarded-Bug?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing Badges Thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/missing-badges-thread)

I have answered [one of the questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93236/bayes-theorem-in-a-simple-example/93247#93247) on Math Stack exchange and have 25 points on it. But, I have not been awarded Good Answer Badge. Is it a bug?

Comment: It takes more than one upvote and answer acceptance to earn "Good Answer"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a bug.  You need the net vote count to be 25, not the number of points earned for the answer.

If you go to the badge tab and click on the Good Answer badge, you'll get a list [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/24/good-answer).  If you then click on one of the answers listed there, you'll see an answer with a net vote count of at least 25.  This is indicative of a general procedure for figuring out what some of the question and answer badges mean if you don't find the initial description clear.  (This wouldn't help for some badges, such as those related to flagging or editing.)

See also the post "[Badge descriptions ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/badge-descriptions-ambiguous)" on meta.stackoverflow.com.